# Reverse proxy using haproxy redirection of node-red dashboard

Tags: haproxy, pfsense

I have multiple node-red servers running behind a HAProxy reverse proxy which runs as apart of a pfSense box.

I want to access different node-red instances by accessing the pfSense box at different path. For example:

http://example.com/node-red1 --> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
http://example.com/node-red2 --> yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/

Also I need to access the dashboard of node ui in the same way, e.g.:

http://example.com/node-red1/ui --> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ui
http://example.com/node-red2/ui --> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ui

I though that this would be easy to achieve with HAProxy but I keep having problems. I have done the following:

1. Created a FrontEnd with different access control lists:

```
    Path starts with: node-red1 --> Action: Use backend node-red1 
    Path starts with: node-red2 --> Action: USe backend node-red2
```

2. Created two different BackEnds:

   **Backend node-red1:**

   Server: Forward To xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

   **Backend node-red2**

   Server: Forward To yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Unfortunately, although the traffic is sent to the correct server, the node-red server cannot handle path `/node-red1` or `/node-red1/ui` and therefore I get page not found 404. I assumed that rewriting the path should work, but I cannot get it to work.

Can someone help me with setting up HAProxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, maybe the port number is missing

http://node-red1.example.com --> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1880